# User module functions undefined in custom module

Tags: users

I am attempting to use the user_password() and user_save() functions from user.module in my custom module file, but I only receive the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_save() C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7.38\sites\all\modules\(modulename)\(modulename).module on line 1037

I get a similar error if I comment out all of my code, leaving the module file as

```
<?php
user_save();
```

As far as I know, if the only problem was the lack of parameters, it chould be an entirely different error, not 'Call to undefined function'.

The function in which I'm trying to use user_password() and user_save() is as follows:

```
function create_user_by_id($id){
    $password = user_password(8);
    $info = soap_info($id);
    $fields = array(
        'name' => $id,
        'mail' => $info['mail'],
        'pass' => $password,
        'status' => 1,
        'init' => 'email address',
        'roles' => array(
            DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_ROLE => 'cas authenticated user'
        )
    );
    $account = user_save('', $fields);
    drupal_mail(
        'user', 
        'register_no_approval_required', 
        $info['mail'], 
        NULL, 
        array('account' => $account), 
        variable_get('site_mail', 'noreply@example.com'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are just calling a function without telling drupal how to access that function , you can tell drupal about where to find this function using this code :

```
 module_load_include('module', 'user', 'user.module');
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be automatically included as a core module. Won't make that mistake again! However, I should note that module_load_include accepts as parameters a file extension, module name, and file name. As such, to find 'user.module' in module 'user', the code should be `module_load_include('module', 'user', 'user.module');`

Comment: Wow, I mistyped my correction. It should be `module_load_include('module', 'user', 'user');`